# Send an email for each row in a SAS data set

Tags: macros, sas

I have a data set (work.employees) where each field is an element of an email to be sent out. Example record: Smith, John, John.Smith@Company.com, JohnsManager@Company.com. For each record, I need to send a separate email based on the information there. I can send one email with macro variables, and have piddled around with a data *null* email, but the iteration isn't happening. Suggestions would be very appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Hi, welcome to stack overflow. Please refer the [ask] link for 
more details on how to ask a question and update your question accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

So you want to send email notification through sas? The issue is two folded. First you need to make sure your SMTP server is properly configured in SAS. Secondly you have to make the required mailing software.

For first bit follow the guide in http://support.sas.com/kb/19/767.html

Now what you want (apparently) is to parse/select the emails. I'm going to assume you only select them from data set.

```
Proc sql;
     select distinct(emails) into: resplist separated by ' '  from mail_set where emails like '%@%'; 
/*Here I'm selecting only those that have @ mark in the cells. 
You can add parser as you need. (question is a bit oddly worded.*/
quit;
```

Alternatively, you can hardCode the addresses. (I suggest you try 1st with this so you know your sending code works.

```
%let respList="Frist.last@email.com" "Second.Recipiant@email.com";


FILENAME Mailbox EMAIL &respList.
Subject="Email delivery for you";
DATA _NULL_;
    FILE Mailbox;
    PUT "Good day,";
    put ;
    PUT "Remain calm. This is a test.";
    PUT ;
run;
```

You can also add sas datasets informatin, but bear in mind that spamming stuff through email is usually bad idea.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to send one email per record, it's better to use the `!EM_` directives in your datastep.

http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lrdict/64316/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a002058232.htm

```
filename reports email "Jim.Smith@work.com"; 

data _null_;    
   file reports;    
   length name dept $ 21;    
   input name dept;    
   put '!EM_TO! ' name;       
   put '!EM_SUBJECT! Report for ' dept;      
   put name ',';    
   put 'Here is the latest report for ' dept '.' ;    
   if dept='marketing' then    
      put '!EM_ATTACH! c:\mktrept.txt';  
   else  /* ATTACH the appropriate report */       
      put '!EM_ATTACH! c:\devrept.txt';
      put '!EM_SEND!';       
      put '!EM_NEWMSG!';     
      put '!EM_ABORT!';      
   datalines; 
Susan          marketing 
Peter          marketing 
Alma           development 
Andre          development 
;
run;
```